# Vue Router reporting no match found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am having issues with Vue Router. I'm new so forgive me for any obvious mistakes how I've been searching around for similar issues and even read the Vue-Router guide however nothing stands out as being wrong.

I have a list of top-level routes (`/`, `/tags`, `/people`, etc.) which have all worked fine. The `/tags` route for example will just show a page listing all the tags and I want have each one link to its own page for editing, so that's what I've setup:

```
<router-link :to="`/tags/${tag.id}`" v-text="tag.name" />
```

I've omitted the other top-level routes from my routes file code below so as not to clutter anything.

```js
// @/router/index.ts
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
import Tags from '@/views/Tags/index.vue'
import SingleTag from '@/views/Tags/Single.vue'

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    {
        path: '/tags',
        name: 'Tags',
        component: Tags,
    },
    {
        path: '/tags/:id',
        name: 'Tags',
        component: SingleTag,
    },
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
})

export default router
```

As you can see here, I've created a separate route with accepts an id. This matches the `router-link` above, however nothing works. It just lists the `Tags` component instead. If I swap the order of these two routes, I just a bunch of warnings in console such as:

> No match found for location with path "/tags/13"

As I would prefer to have the specific id route as a child of the listing page, that's what I had tried first, but this just has the same issue as the routes as they're listed above.

Now what I did manage to get working is by changing the specific id route to `/tag/:id` instead, however I don't want that if possible. I want to keep it as `/tags/:id` and have it as a child of the main one. Is this going to be possible or am I forced to keep it as `/tag/:id`?

Comment: Try having the route object like

Comment: `
{
        path: '/tags',
        name: 'Tags',
        component: Tags,
        children: [{
        path: '/tags/:id',
        name: 'SubTag', // Note this line and do the changes accordingly
        component: SingleTag,
     }] }`

Comment: One thing that might break this is that they have the same name

Comment: @Amaarrockz By giving the child route a unique name, I can see that the route is working however it's still using the `Tags` component over the `SingleTag` one.

Comment: Do not use `children` option ([Nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)) - the name in the docs is really misleading as the feature is not needed for route nesting but instead for component nesting (children route even does not need to match) - so in your examle `Tags` component will be rendered always and `Tag` component will be render inside it (`Tags` must contain another `<router-view>` for that to work). But as you don't want that, do not use `children`

Comment: @MichalLevý I literally just noticed that. Had somehow missed that little bit when reading the docs. With that in mind, how can I get both routes to work without nesting them?

Comment: Actually, no idea what did it but I seem to have it working. I can only think that I had some small typo that I never caught, and retyping seemed to do the trick.

Comment: yes, [it seems so](https://paths.esm.dev/?p=AAMeJVyAwRAZzFDAgxEuwFgC0QQAQA..&t=/tags/255#) (great tool to debug router matching)